# How long do university libraries keep old copies of dissertations?

Tags: thesis

How can I get a copy of a dissertation that I need for my research?

Comment: Go to a good library and check what they have on offer...

Comment: Libraries generally try to keep them forever. My PhD thesis is entirely digital and available online, but it was required to print one copy for long term preservation as a last resort in case pdfs go extinct.

Comment: In the US, many universities required (and may still) that dissertations be catalogued by Proquest, which used to use the name University Microfilms: https://www.proquest.com/products-services/dissertations/. You can order reprints from them. But they aren't free. Libraries may be able to get you a temporary copy for free.

Comment: Disagree with "hold".  The question is a little awkwardly written between title and question, but other than that seems very on topic.  General academic question.  Good one.  Buffy's comment in particular is the core of a good answer.

Comment: The latest edit makes the question unclear. Are you interested in how long a university library *typically* keeps copies of theses? Or are you interested in how you'd go about getting hold of some old thesis?

Answer (score 2):

I suspect that that differs from university to university, and country to country, but I would not be surprised if the answer is "for as long as they can preserve the paper". I remember finding the master's thesis of my (fairly old) teacher when I was a high-school student.

On the other hand, it may be the policy of some university / library to digitalize them  (or in the old days, to put them on microfilm) after a given amount of time to save space in the library. This depends on how much money / time they have for that effort, and how much space they have in the library. It is easy to imagine huge differences between universities and countries in these different costs, resulting in different policies.

Regardless, you should expect that people will be able to find your dissertation for as long as you live (and afterwards).

Comment: There are digitizing programs going on in many libraries to prolong the existence of many documents... And just been to the British Library to locate the thesis of one of my Professors - done in 1987 and it is there...

Comment: In Germany: Forever, unless the library burns down, and since you have to hand in many copies you should be able to locate an issue. Use worldcat.org to locate copies worldwide. And yes, please re-open the question.